# Removing horizontal lines in audio spectrogram

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I have an audio spectrogram that has several horizontal lines in it that I am trying to remove.

The lines appear at 2kHz, 4kHz, and 6kHz and I've tried de-noising methods with scipy but have not been able to remove the lines.

Is there a way in scipy I can remove these horizontal lines without messing with the rest of the audio quality?

[image: spectrum]

Comment: Can you use the [notch filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.iirnotch.html) provided by Scipy? Creating a [mcve] will make it easier for people to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Those lines probably represent some kind of resonance (maybe of the data acquisition equipment). You can perform whitening by removing median value of each of the spectrums in the spectrogram.